# Jquery submit and post to post a form unable to return data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have problem with jquery submit and post. I would like to submit a form and post it to my php for a check, and return the php result back to the form. However, I have problem with the returning of data, it basically ignores the result.

This is my html form:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <p id="status">Status:</p>
    <p class="text">
        <label for="name" class="label">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p class="text">
        <label for="email" class="label">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="send_btn" id="send_btn" value="Send" />
    </p>
</form>
```

This is my javascript to do the submit and post:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        $.post('notify.php', {name: name, email: email}, function(data) {
            $('#status').html(data);
        });

});
```

This is the php that does the check and return the data:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email']))
{
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);

    if ($name == "myname")
    {
        $output = 'It matches!';
    }
    else
    {
        $output = 'No matches!";
    }
}
?>
```

Can please highlight what has gone wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Your PHP doesn't print anything!!! you miss an echo/print.

Comment: It also has syntax error related to the quotes at the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `echo` or `die` in your php script, so your function can get the results.

So, change your script to this:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email']))
{
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);

    if ($name == "myname")
    {
        $output = 'It matches!';
    }
    else
    {
        $output = 'No matches!';
    }

    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Notice the third to last line, where I am calling `echo $output` - whatever you echo will be returned from your ajax call. If you want to get more complex, you should return a JSON object.

```
$results = array("result" => "It Matches!", "foo" => "bar");
echo json_encode($results);
```

**EDIT:** You also need to change the `"` to a `'` at the end of your else.

Answer (score 1):

Print the answer on PHP
as comment suggest
     echo $output;

at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

In your php code, you aren't actually writing $output to the page.

```
<?php
    // your code

    echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

dont forget

**return false;**

If u forget it, the form when submit will refesh and ajax will fail ;

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        $.post('notify.php', {name: name, email: email}, function(data) {
            $('#status').html(data);
        });
    return false;       
});
```